# what's make GPU programs non-preemptible?

Tags: parallel-processing, operating-system, gpu, gpgpu

Modern operating systems have no support for **GPUs**, treating them more or less as a normal I/O device.there some researches in that areas attempt to managing **GPUs** at operating system level,but they claim that the **GPU** programs are **non-preemptible**: once a work unit has been started, it’s impossible to interrupt it without destroying the channel’s data.

> so what i am asking is:

- Is it true that it's non-preemtible?
- If it's non-preemtible ,what make it non-preemtible ,is it because of hardware
  design or what is the reason?
- If it non-preemtible what we need to make it preemtible?

i'll be highly appreciated if someone can give a clear explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPU preempt themselves all the time, but only with other work items from the same kernel. If a compute unit is waiting on a memory read or write it will execute other work items. It's single instruction multiple threads essentially. However, it doesn't make sense to stop a job part way through and switch to a different job. You'd need to keep track of an enormous amount of state (unlike a serial processor that just has a register set, you'd have all that multiplied by the number of compute units). GPU jobs are all designed to run quickly, so cycling jobs through the system is more efficient that switching between partially complete jobs. That all said, some modern GPUs divide up the hardware and can have different parts working on different jobs at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of over simplification:

Let's say I have a solid object defined within the GPU. For simplicity, let's say that the object is a cube and that the GPU maintains 8 vertices (and that the GPU is VERY slow).

Let me start a rotation. I have do a matrix multiplication on each vertex. I do 3 of them. Then I get preempted.

My cube is no longer a cube.

If you wanted it preemtable, you'd need some kind of transaction processing with rollback (slowing things down) and hardware support giving a preemptable interface.